# Prevent drop until pointer is dropped with no_std

Tags: pointers, rust, lifetime

I have a struct that stores a raw pointer to some data:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    x: *const T
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn new(x: &[T]) -> Foo<T> {
        Foo {
            x: &x[0] as *const T
        }
    }
}
```

The data is actually a slice, but I use the offset method to avoid directly storing the data. The constructor puts the a pointer to the data into the field, and returns the struct. However, if I try to return a `Foo` from a function:

```
fn foo() -> Foo<i32> {
    let x = [1, 2, 3];
    Foo::new(&x)
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("{}", &*foo().x);
    }
}
```

The data is dropped too early, and the field `x` points to garbage. What I want to have happen is the data `x` points to is cloned, and the clone lives for as long as the struct does. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly the problem here is. Do you want to make a new heap allocation and copy the data there, so that `Foo` is self-contained? That would be easy, if you weren't using `no_std`. So why are you doing that? Does your target platform even *have* a heap? And if so, why are you using `no_std`? Please explain *what* you want to achieve, not *how* you want to achieve it, to prevent falling into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't.**

You're trying to escape a pointer to stack data, which is something Rust would forbid you from doing if you were using regular borrowed pointers.  However, by using raw pointers and `unsafe`, you've effectively stripped off the various protections the compiler would normally enforce.

You really, *really* shouldn't be using `unsafe` unless you understand what's happening.

You also cannot extend the lifetime of something created within a function without moving it out.  There is simply *no way* of passing out a pointer (or a borrow) of `x`.

The fix for this is to just *not* do it in the first place.  Use borrowed pointers (`&i32` or `&[i32]`) or owned values (`i32`, `Vec<i32>`).

Another possibility would be to allocate the necessary storage in the *caller* and pass a `&mut` into `foo`, which you can then slice, mutate, and return a borrowed sub-slice to.  That, of course, requires that you can statically define an upper-bound on how much space `foo` will need, but such is life without `std`.

Comment: I could do like you said and allow the caller to specify the lifetime by passing a `&mut Foo`. That would work fine for me, although now I need to figure out how to clone either a `Foo` or a slice.